# Using agsXMPP in Metro-style applications

Tags: xmpp, microsoft-metro

I was trying to use agsXMPP reference in a Metro-style app for Windows 8 but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot find type System.Collections.CollectionBase in module mscorlib.dll
```

I think I need the whole .NET for using agsXMPP and Metro does not have the whole. What can I do? Is there any way to use agsXMPP in Metro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest investigating Matrix for WinRT (Metro) which is the successor to agsXMPP. While it's not free, it's supported (or soon will be).

According to their [forum](http://forum.ag-software.de/), they're working on making Matrix work for Metro/WinRT. Given that their comment suggests that they're needing to rewrite lots of code, it's doubtful that agsXMPP will be easily ported.